# file system query with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a power shell advanced question, I searched for an answer / example without luck.

Query:
I would like to get the N'th newest folder files (no sub-folders) with the condition that the folder contains foo.xml.

Example
Input: Root folder = Z

z:.....\A\B\foo.xml

z:.....\A\B\bar.txt

z:.....\A\B\C\koo.txt

z:.....\A\foo.xml

z:.....\A\abc.doc

z:.....\D\xyz.xls

Output for the query

z:.....\A\B\foo.xml

z:.....\A\B\bar.txt

z:.....\A\foo.xml

z:.....\A\abc.doc

I want to do it with powershell to gain performance (loops in higher language, is too slow).

Comment: Mathias, Thanks a lot. 
Going to try and to measure the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is:

1. Find all "foo.xml" throughout the tree
2. Find the newest files in the parent directories
3. Output their `FullName` (their path) property

This should do:

```
funtion Get-NewestFooFileSibling {
    param(
        [string]$RootPath = 'Z:',
        [string]$FooFile  = 'foo.xml',
        [int]$N = 10
    )

    # Find the foo.xml files, pipe their paths to foreach-object
    Get-ChildItem -Filter $FooFile -Recurse -File -Name |ForEach-Object {
        # Find all sibling files (files in the same directory)
        # sort by when they were created and select only the first $N files
        Get-ChildItem -Path (Split-Path $_ -Parent) -File |Sort CreationTime -Descending |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName -First $N
    }
}
```